# radlistview is not working on nativescript 6.3.0

Tags: nativescript

In my previous times i have worked on some projects on nativescript. but Now, it got updated and i don't  know why my rad-list-view is not working.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
    xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page">
...
...
<lv:RadListView row="1" items="{{ source }}">
            <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
                    <Label text="{{ name }}" textWrap="true" />
                </GridLayout>
            </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        </lv:RadListView>
...
...
```

```
source: [{
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }, {
            name: "Test",
        }],
```

> error:-

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onCreateViewHolder failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.common.js.RadListView.resolveTemplateView', file:'file:///node_modules\nativescript-ui-listview\ui-listview.common.js:532:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.common.js.RadListView.getViewForViewType', file:'file:///node_modules\nativescript-ui-listview\ui-listview.common.js:579:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'ListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder', file:'file:///node_modules\nativescript-ui-listview\ui-listview.js:129:0
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
System.err:     at com.telerik.widget.list.ListViewAdapter_vendor_1544_32_ListViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown Source:27)System.err:     at com.telerik.widget.list.ListViewWrapperAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListViewWrapperAdapter.java:468)
System.err:     at com.telerik.widget.list.ListViewWrapperAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListViewWrapperAdapter.java:20)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
System.err:     at com.telerik.widget.list.RadListView.onLayout(RadListView.java:600)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.CommonLayoutParams.layoutChild(CommonLayoutParams.java:222)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java:354)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.CommonLayoutParams.layoutChild(CommonLayoutParams.java:222)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.GridLayout.onLayout(GridLayout.java:354)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.CommonLayoutParams.layoutChild(CommonLayoutParams.java:222)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.ContentLayout.onLayout(ContentLayout.java:73)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2942)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2457)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1553)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7569)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:958)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:770)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:702)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:944)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

Atleast before webpack I'm able to get on which line of code the error was. but here I'm not even understanding the error. How  to resolve this issue. and how to identify the error in vendor.js which always gives some android code exceptions which is out of scope of cross platform technology as i came here to work with js not with some android code. And i expect only js error which i wrote.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Answer (score 1):

ok, i made a mistake that after creating project i run the command

> npm install -g nativescript

so nativescript version was `6.3.0` whereas i didn't updated `platforms` and `tns-core-modules`

So, i deleted the project and created new one. Then it created matching version of `platforms` and `tns-core-modules` and problem solved

or else we can delete `platforms` and `tns-core-modules` and create new one by

```
tns platform remove android    
tns platform add android   
npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save
```